# USB host mode not working on Samsung Galaxy S using CyanogenMod

Tags: usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

I am using CyanogenMod 10.1.0-RC3 (Android 4.2.2) on my Samsung Galaxy S Plus (GT-I9001). I have read Android 4 supports USB on the go, so I wanted to give it a try.

I bought a USB OTG cable, and connected a USB stick (formatted FAT32) to my phone. Nothing happened. After reading [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support), I installed [USB Host diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics), and my device says:

> **Android API**
>
> Claims support: Yes
>
> Classes found: Yes
>
> Device Detected: No

I bought a new USB OTG cable to be sure this is not the problem, but the result is the same.

What am I missing? I have the right Android version, an appropriate cable, no special hardware (just a USB stick - I tried with different ones). Maybe I need the host mode drivers? But I don't know where to find them, and I am not sure if this is my problem.

What can cause my issue and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galaxy S Plus (i9001) needs an external power source to have a working USB OTG. See this link on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1450298) for more information (it's for the i9000, but does also apply).

According to [GSMArena's spec](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9001_galaxy_s_plus-3908.php) (*USB: Yes, microUSB v2.0*) the i9001 firmware doesn't originally support USB-OTG ([compare the S3's spec](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php), but 3rd party firmware added this later on. It does however not function without external 5V power.

Comment: Yes, with the original Firmware (Android 2.3) it does not support USB OTG because this feature was introduced in Android 3. But I am using CyanogenMod with Android 4 - which has USB OTG support.

Comment: Most of all, the chipset does need to support this mode  at all. Which obviously isn't the case. If it indeed *does* support it, then I'd say it's the cable that's wrong (but I'm not so sure about that).

Comment: I tried two different, new cables, so I hope this is not the case...

Comment: There can be more reasons: This [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1450298) says that the GS i9000 needs an external power source to be able to act as USB Host. While the i9001 has different hardware it might as well be possible that you need this too.

Comment: PS: Even if a device provides power it's a good idea to use an external power source. E.g., one of my thumb drives doesn't work because it draws more current than my phone will provide.

Comment: The external power source solved the problem, thanks :)

Comment: Nice! I changed my answer accordingly. Would be kind if you upvote/accept :-)