# Android 4.1 tablet Model M736 not recognizing keyboard when connected through 4 port usb hub

Tags: usb

I am having a Belkin 4 port USB hub and an Android 4.1 tablet Model M736 made by Kocaso. I am trying to connect USB keyboard and a USB WiFi dongle to the hub and not able to see either of the devicces. Tried only the keyboard connected to the hub yet not able to recognize that a keyboard exists. But individually the devices work when connected directly to tablet. Could it be that the USB hub isnot able to support enough power when connected to the tablet.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Connect a self powered USB hub and try again.

USB-OTG ports often provide little power that's suitable for one device only, but may already fail for power hungry devices like very fast USB thumb drives, wifi dongles or 2.5in USB hard disk enclosures. Your setup very probably draws too much.

You can use any 3rd party USB power bank if you need it on-the-go. Your hub may have a power input connector already. Finding the right cable might be an issue though. Here's some related info, someone asked this for the SGS i9000 which doesn't provide power at all: [USB host mode not working on Samsung Galaxy S using CyanogenMod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47610/usb-host-mode-not-working-on-samsung-galaxy-s-using-cyanogenmod/47612#47612)