# USB OTG support on Samsung Galaxy Chat B5330

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I have Samsung Galaxy Chat B5330 and I was wondering if there is a way to get USB-OTG support on this.

[image: Samsung Galaxy Chat B5330]

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the testing of other users on [Chainfire's USB Host Diagnostics site](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/?search=B5330), there's **NO** USB OTG support for GT-B5330.

See also: [How can I determine if my device has USB Host Mode (OTG) support?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support)