# Does the Grand Neo GT i9060 have USB OTG?

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-grand

Does the Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo GT-i9060 have USB OTG ([usb-on-the-go](/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go))? Can I instantly watch movies directly from OTG without copying files into my phone? If not, is there any other way to get OTG working?

Answer (score 2):

The Galaxy Grand Neo [from my reading](http://www.phonemore.com/compare/phones/samsung-galaxy-grand-neo-gt-i9060-8gb-vs-samsung-galaxy-s3-gt-i9300-16gb/951525) does not support USB OTG.

You could just stream videos onto your phone from your PC / Desktop, and there are plenty of apps to do that.

There is some great [further reading](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support) in this question "How can I determine if my device has USB host mode & USB OTG Support."

Comment: That guide is to how make an USB OTG cable (you can buy it for 1$) but it's not going to work anyway if it's not supported by the phone.

Comment: Yep, moment of madness there. Deleted, cheers @crayon