# How can I make my USB headset work correctly?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, htc-one

My phone is an HTC One running Android 4.4.2, and the headset is a Logitech G35. I've tried connecting the headset to the phone with a USB OTG cable several times with mixed results:

- The buttons on the headset (play/pause, skip, volume) always work.
- Sound sometimes comes out of the phone, sometimes comes out of the headset, and sometimes doesn't come out at all.
- When sound DOES come out of the headset, it's either at "full volume" (not as loud as I would expect it to be) or muted. The phone won't let me set it to anything in between.
- Someone called once while I had sound coming out of it: the phone used the built-in speakers & mic for the call.

It works just fine with my laptop (running Linux Mint) so it shouldn't need any special drivers. I'd like to make it work properly because it sounds much better than my earbuds and is pretty good at blocking out noise. I haven't really tried the mic and I'm not too worried about it. What do I need to do to make it work? Am I just overlooking a setting or something?

Update: I found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support?rq=1) and [ran the diagnostic](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/?search=543132). It looks like it should have full support for USB devices, so I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: I haven't been able to get *any* audio output with my G35 headset and Samsung S8. Perhaps there's something about the G35 that Android doesn't like because certainly Android USB OTG works with some other USB headsets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for the otg to USB connector, some of the wire may be loose.
2. Your mobile software drives for USB headphone may get crashed, so you may get mixed result. Check for your system updates in your mobile. It may fix the issue.
3. Your headphone may have chipset that some time block the incoming otg signals.

I am using Lenovo K4 mobile and Zebronics iron head USB headset. Hearing audio and video through otg to USB female. I have few creeping sound for 2o Sec for every track for songs, but work great after that..