# how does OTG enabler app work?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, htc-desire, kernel, usb-drivers, usb-mass-storage

There is a device has no USB OTG signal, but the cheker says: "your device OS has USB OTG API, check for USB OTG kernel or driver signal"
OS v.6.0.1 M, i cant find OTG enabler support it.
I want to learn how does OTG enabler work? and What are the files that deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work unless your mobile supports it.
OTG requires a source of power that need for it to work. Some mobile devices fails to provide enough power for OTG to power up the USB drives etc.
I personally tried in dozens of my mobiles and tablets. Nothing worked!

**not sure about rooted devices**

Comment: I think that right, but what about the case of manufacture? it says this device supports USB. When it says that, it should think about USB power supply

Comment: If it says it supports OTG then it has to work!

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support           <- check this link. And this link which is a HTC blog it says, they doesn't guarantee the OTG support with 3rd party

Comment: HTC blog -> http://blog.htc.com/usb-otg/  and also some mobiles of same model might have an OTG variant in one country release but not in another. Usually for cheaper market.