# Can I use an external hard drive with an Android phone?

Tags: usb, external-sd, usb-on-the-go

For years I've been downloading things onto my Android then transferring them to SD cards via the usb port connected to a card-reader.

Could I use a basic unpowered external hard drive instead, such as a Sonnics? (Phone is not rooted)

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible but not with all devices**

- USB OTG (USB On the Go) capability of the device both from the hardware and ROM (specifically kernel) decides whether your device is capable of connecting to a hard drive.
- You would need to search on Internet if your device supports it or not. There are apps on Play Store, that can tell you but they require root (usually )
- Rooting is not required if your device supports OTG connection to hard drive. Rooting helps in flashing a custom kernel that can enable OTG , provided your hardware supports and your device is supported by developers who make custom ROMs and kernels (popular devices are supported (search on [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/) for your specific device model)
- Also be aware that certain devices support OTG capability in terms of connecting a flash drive but not external hard disc (powered externally or not )

For more, see [usb-on-the-go](/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go) ( tag added to the question ) and [frequent questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go?sort=frequent) and [How can I determine if my device has USB Host Mode (OTG) support?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/36887/131553)